# Decode Ogg/Opus file

Tags: c++, opus

I have a very small piece of C++ code that tries to open an ogg/opus coded file and uses the opus API in order to decode it with the function opus_decode(). The thing is that almost the half of the opus_decode() calls that I do for the same sound return negative (error) codes.. -4 and -2 (invalid package and buffer too short) that I can`t solve. The output is like

> N decoded: 960 N decoded: -4 N decoded: -4 N decoded: 960 N decoded:
>   -4 N decoded: 1920 N decoded: 960 N decoded: -4 N decoded: -4

and so on.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <opus/opus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define LEN 1024
#define FREQ 48000
#define CHANNELS 1
#define FRAMESIZE 1920

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int size = opus_decoder_get_size(CHANNELS);

    OpusDecoder *decoders = (OpusDecoder*)malloc(size);
    int error = opus_decoder_init(decoders, FREQ, CHANNELS);

    std::ifstream inputfile;
    inputfile.open("/home/vir/Descargas/detodos.opus"); //48000Hz, Mono

    char input[LEN];

    opus_int16 *data = (opus_int16*)calloc(CHANNELS*FRAMESIZE,sizeof(opus_int16));


    if(inputfile.is_open())
        while (!inputfile.eof()) {

            inputfile >> input;         

            std::cerr << "N decoded: " << opus_decode(decoders, (const unsigned char*)&input[0], LEN, data, FRAMESIZE, 0)  << "\n";

        }


    return error;
}
```

Comment: Should this be decoded synchronously or asynchronously?

Answer (score 8):

It seems you are using Opus-Tools instead of OpusFile.  Obviously you have linked against the `libopus.a` library, but you also need to download and build OpusFile 0.7 and link your program against `libopusfile.a` created from building OpusFile.  Include `opusfile.h` in your program from OpusFile 0.7.  Lastly you need to download and build the libogg library from downloading libogg 1.3.2 from [xiph.org/downloads](https://xiph.org/downloads) and link against libogg library.

[This link](https://www.opus-codec.org/docs/opusfile_api-0.7/group__stream__open__close.html) is the documentation explaining how to open and close ogg opus streams for decoding.

Make sure you have an ogg opus file and open the stream using...

```
OggOpusFile *file = op_open_file(inputfile, error)(inputfile is char* inputfile and error is an int pointer)
```

Close the stream with `op_free(file)`.  This is the [function documentation](https://www.opus-codec.org/docs/opusfile_api-0.7/group__stream__decoding.html) to actually decode an ogg opus stream.  Before you call op_free decode the audio data with...

```
op_read(file,buffer,bufferSize,null), buffer is opus_int16 pcm[120*48*2]
```

`bufferSize` is `sizeof(pcm)/sizeof(*pcm)`. `op_read` will decode more of the file, so put it in a `for` loop until `op_read` returns `0`.